# past tense conjugation これ以上は 死タからその 前に殺さナいと

Tags: particle-と, katakana, particle-から, past

> これ以上は 死タからその 前に殺さナいと

I find it perplexing that 死タからそ is conjugated in the past tense. It being the reason (-から) for 殺さナいと, shouldn't it be in present tense? Or am I mixing it up and (-と) takes precedence? Which still wouldn't further my understanding of why this is past tense? Or is he thinking he's already dead.

Comment: 「死タから」 makes no sense regardless of the tense.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to replace the Katakana. It should be read as: これ以上は 死たからその 前に殺さないと

Comment: Still doesn't make sense no matter how you break that sentence down: 死た・から・その because the base form for dying is 死ぬ and other forms are 死んだ・死んでる・死にます・死す・死した. There must be a typo there somewhere.

Comment: The author made a typo, then, I guess. Though I'm still wishing someone could help me about the use of both particles in the same sentence, combined with a past tense.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence. You should forget this sentence because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I suppose it's a circling back to the kanji from 死ぬ → タヒる → タヒた → 死た. It's a form a slang, playing on the fact that the kanji for to die is composed of the katakanas タ and ヒ.

Comment: I think it should be 死**だ**から, right?

Comment: Agreed, that makes the most sense.　これ以上は死　だから、その前に殺さないと = Continuing like this there is  death (for us), so before that we must kill (him)

Comment: Well, yesterday i eventually went with: "Any more and I'm dead - I need to kill him before that." But the past tense really surprises me still...

Answer (score 1):

My take is that it should be 死ヌ not 死タ. タ and ヌ are visually similar so someone (or an algorithm?) might have misrecognized it. In standard orthography, the entire sentence would be:

> これ以上は死ぬから、その前に殺さないと。

(I assume the use of katakana is a stylistic choice to illustrate a not-normal way of talking.)

I don't know what it exactly means, though, because the subject and the object are made implicit. It says 死ぬ but who will die? It says 殺さないと but who must be killed? We will need the larger context to be sure.

One possible interpretation (with a hypothetical context I'm making up) is that "we are bound to die [because of the opponent's actions], we need to kill him [=the opponent] sooner [than something that he controls kills us]".

Answer (score 0):

first しんでいたから &second ころさなきゃ

Comment: 「これ以上は死んでいたからその前に殺さなきゃ」って意味不明なんですけど・・

Comment: I don't understand it either. Thank you but I'm really wondering about why this past tense with the two particles together in the same sentence. I actually wished for an explanation of the why, then myself try to translate it, rather than that... But thank you anyway.